# 3blue1brown | 1 problem related in getting manim to run (SquareToCircle example)

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, manim

I'm following the instructions of the tutorial (https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2018/06/11/learning-how-to-animate-videos-using-manim-series-a-journey/) but, when I type

```
(manim37) C:\Users\PaKo>python3 C:\Users\PaKo\Desktop\Python\3blue_1brown\manim-master\extract_scene.py C:\Users\PaKo\Desktop\Python\3blue_1brown\manim-master\example_scenes.py
SquareToCircle -pl
```

I get the following: (I'm working in python 3.7)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PaKo\Desktop\Python\3blue_1brown\manim-master\extract_scene.py", line 299, in
main()
File "C:\Users\PaKo\Desktop\Python\3blue_1brown\manim-master\extract_scene.py", line 259, in main
module = get_module(config["file"])
File "C:\Users\PaKo\Desktop\Python\3blue_1brown\manim-master\extract_scene.py", line 254, in get_module
return importlib.import_module(module_name)
File "C:\Users\PaKo\Anaconda2\envs\manim36\lib\importlib_init_.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "< frozen importlib._bootstrap >", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:'
```

Can you help me to solve this issue so I can visualize the video?
Thank you in advanced,

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are speaking of was posted a few months earlier from your post, and they have a notice:

```
Important Note:  These posts are based on an earlier version of manim which uses Python 2.7.  
The latest version of manim is using Python 3.  
To follow along with these posts, use Python 2.7 and the May 9, 2018 commit of manim.
```

I'd put high odds on the instructions in there being outdated.

It's unlikely that you haven't already solved the problem by now, but for posterity I'll try to answer your question:

If you have installed manim correctly, you are probably just entering the wrong command. The command for running manim has changed, so I would recommend `cd`-ing into your manim installation directory (`manim-master` if you downloaded from github) and running:

`python -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl`
instead of what you previously entered.

It may also be possible that you installed the python3 version of manim while you are running with python2. Try `python3` instead of `python` instead in that case.